# Перемнные окружения и пароли БД

Tags: php

Где то давно слышал, что в php безопаснее хранить логин и пароль от базы данных в переменных окружения ($_ENV), **а не в самом php скрипте**. Действительно ли это так? И в чем плюсы и минусы такого способа хранения?

Comment: `безопаснее хранить логин и пароль от базы данных в переменных окружения ($_ENV), а не в самом php скрипте`. Если файлы каким-то образом уйдут - да. Вообще конфиги следует хранить отдельно. А если база данных слушает только локалхост, и сервер - не шаред хостинг, а персональный VDS - можно вообще без пароля обходиться.

Comment: @total-pusher Подскажите, в чем плюсы и минусы обоих способов хранения (в скрипте и в переменных окружения). И какой способ, на ваш взгляд, безопаснее?

Comment: ENV - более удобный для Docker, например. Он позволяет выкатывать образ системы без правки файлов напрямую. Безопасность практически одинаковая, если не делать ошибок. Если человек имеет доступ к файлу, он узнает пароль в явном виде. Размещайте конфиги выше корня веб-документов. НЕ кладите в git конфиги. НЕ используйте FTP в чистом виде. Если человек сможет вписать в скрипт "показать окружение" - он увидит пароль, как его не прячь. Также переменные окружения можно увидеть руту через `cat /proc/пид-процесса/environ` - значит от администратора сервера не спрятаться :)